# Spring boot admin Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: spring-boot, url, kubernetes, admin, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to add an spring boot admin interface to some microservice that are deployed in kubernetes cluster. the spring boot admin app has the following configuration:

```
spring:
        application:
          name: administrator-interface
        boot:
          admin:
            context-path: "/ui"
      server:
        use-forward-headers: true
```

The kubernetes cluster has an ingress that works as an api gateway:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
  annotations:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    {{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ $host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/(.+)
            backend:
              serviceName: administrator-interface-back
              servicePort: 8080
    {{- end -}}
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
{{ toYaml .Values.ingress.tls | indent 4 }}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

when I try to see the spring boot admin ui I had the following error:

URL in explorer: https://XXXXXX(thisisgivenBYDNS)/admin/ui

```
GET https://XXXXXX/ui/assets/css/chunk-common.6aba055e.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

The URL is wrong because it should be https://XXXXXX/admin/ui/assets/css/chunk-common.6aba055e.css

It is not adding the /admin path that is given by the ingess

How can i solve this and configure an aditional path to serve the static content in the request from the right URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the ingress yaml

Comment: posted by editing it.

Comment: what is the correct link your spring boot app/service are listening to serve the requests? `/` `/ui` or `/admin/ui` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Spring boot admin has a tool for that called "public URL"

```
      spring:
        application:
          name: administrator-interface
        boot:
          admin:
            context-path: "/ui"
            ui:
              public-url: "https://XXX/admin/ui"
      server:
        use-forward-headers: true
```

whith such configuration I am telling spring boot admin that i want to connect with a context /ui but when trying to load resources it should make the request to /admin/ui.

Now i can connect with the interface trought https:/XXX/ui and is sending request to load resources from https://XXX/admin/ui adding the prefix set by ingress

Thank you @Noé

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your spring boot admin interface has no way to know that you're using "/admin" suburl.

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` ask nginx to rewrite your url matching the second group.
So when you're hitting: `https://XXXXX/admin/ui` nginx rewrite your url to `https://XXXXXX/ui` and then send it to spring boot.

I don't know well spring boot  but you should have a way to provide him a suburl so instead of serving to `/ui` it server to `/$BASE_URL/ui`.

Then weather how it works you might need to change how nginx rewrite the url by something like:

- `path: ^(/admin/)(.+)\`
- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $1/$2`